# Streams from DyanamoDB Mapper Single BatchSave operation triggering multiple events in lambda

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using Java to insert multiple items into DynamoDB using batchSave method. The table has Streams enabled. I want the streams to trigger the lambda just once for a single batchSave. Should I be using some other Method to push multiple items in the DB?

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: What is your purpose in attempting this? Do you just want to save lambda costs, or are there other reasons?

Comment: For every batchSave operation, I want to make an entry in another table. Currently multiple entries are being created for a single batchSave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved by increasing the batchSize which was 1 by default.

Comment: Note that doesn't actually invoke the lambda once per batch save. It might invoke the lambda once for many rapid-fire saves, and in fact one save might be written to multiple partitions which would cause multiple invocations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to guarantee at scale, as each DynamoDB partition will have its own shard in the stream. If you insert a batch you may see the items appear in different lambdas, as each item could belong to a different partition and wind up in a different stream.

In addition, streams can only process 6MB of data in a single invocation, while a BatchWriteItem operation can send 16MB of data.

Comment: Thanks, Ross. Presently my data is not very huge so this won't be a problem.